# how to calculate the correlation between one gene and the other genes

Tags: r, shiny, correlation

I want to find the correlation of one gene that with other genes. I will put this function into shiny at last.

I mean when I select input one gene, I can get how many other genes are closely correlated to this one. And these correlated genes can output in mainpanel even can be downlaod as a text or excel file.

Forgive my inappropriate expression because I'm new to it.

My sample FPKM gene counts below:

```
##  library(shiny)
##  library(dplyr)
##  library(tidyr)
##  library(ggplot2)

###
mean_data <- data.frame(
  Name = c(paste0("Gene_", LETTERS[1:20])),
  matx <- matrix(sample(1:1000, 1000, replace = T), nrow = 20)
)
names(mean_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Sample_", 1:50))
rownames(mean_data)<-mean_data[,1]
mean_data<-mean_data[,-1]

## I don't know the code below is right or not . But I wanna the correlation between the input one and the others 

corResult=apply(mean_data,1,function(x){
  cor(x[1:25],x[26:50],method="spearman")
})
hist(corResult)


corResult_test=apply(mean_data,1,function(x){
  cor.test(x[1:25],x[26:50],method="spearman",exact = F)$p.value
})
table(abs(corResult)>0.65 & corResult_test<0.05)
```

Can somebody help me ? Give me a appropriate method .

Vary thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `corr.test` from the `psych` package; that should do what you want:

```r
library(psych)
set.seed(7)
mean_data <- data.frame(
    Name = c(paste0("Gene_", LETTERS[1:20])),
    matx <- matrix(sample(1:1000, 1000, replace = T), nrow = 20)
)
names(mean_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Sample_", 1:50))
rownames(mean_data) <- mean_data[,1]
mean_data <- mean_data[,-1]

myCor <- function(x="Gene_A", mat=mean_data, pval=.05, R=.65, method="spearman"){
    tm <- corr.test(t(mat[x,,drop=FALSE]),
                           y = t(mat), use = "pairwise", method=method, adjust="holm", 
                           alpha=pval, ci=TRUE, minlength=5)
    res <- setdiff(colnames(tm$r)[which(with(tm, abs(r) > R & p < pval))], x)
   if(length(res) > 0) res 
}

res <- sapply(rownames(mean_data), myCor, pval=.1, R=.3) 
res[lengths(res) > 0]
#> $Gene_A
#> [1] "Gene_K"
#> 
#> $Gene_H
#> [1] "Gene_K"
#> 
#> $Gene_K
#> [1] "Gene_A" "Gene_H"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. I think it is useful to me. But the "R=.65" I don't understand .Can you explain it.

And I don't know if I should use the FPKM normalized gene expresion matrix or DEG matrix with corr.test ? 

Why the R and pval before and later is not consistent ? Forgive me plz. I 'm new to this part.

Comment: You can pass additional parameters to the `myCor` function in the `sapply` function by providing them this way. If you don't pass any, it will use the defaults set in the `myCor` function. Here I used R=.3 and pval=.1 to demonstrate the output, since your example would not yield anything with your desired cutoffs.

Comment: Yeah ， I understood what you mean about R. Vary thankful.
Could you answer this quesion:
I don't know if I should use the FPKM normalized gene expresion matrix or DEG matrix with corr.test ?  I think it's absolutely right for me to choose the FPKM normalized gene expresion matrix as the input object of corr.test ? Am I right or not ?

Comment: Have a look at e.g. https://hbctraining.github.io/DGE_workshop_salmon/lessons/02_DGE_count_normalization.html or https://www.biostars.org/p/328345/ to get an idea what is suitable in your scenario. I would probably use vst-transformed counts, personally.

Comment: Vary thankful . I learnen a lot from you .

My last question:

When I input one gene each as x each time , I can get a result of the correlation between this gene and the other genes . I want the result will shows with  gene name, correlation , and p value  in a dataframe. If this ,what should I do with the res in the end?